# Scale the images to fill the screen in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new to Android layouts. Could you please help me scale teh images to cover width and height of the white space.

Here is the screen.

its all tilted to right side. how can I make it to fill the screen

here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/jkmenu1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/atm"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/airport"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/birthday"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/atm" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/currency"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/birthday"
              android:layout_alignTop="@+id/classifieds"
              android:src="@drawable/currency"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/education"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/coffee"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/education" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/coffee"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/coffee" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/bar"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_above="@+id/birthday"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/bar" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/birthday"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/atm"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/coffee"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/bithday" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/beauty"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/atm"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/beauty" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/airport"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_above="@+id/beauty"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beauty"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/airport" />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/classifieds"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beauty"
              android:layout_alignTop="@+id/education"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:src="@drawable/classifieds" />

      </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you all guys

SOlution for adding space is

I added

```
<View android:layout_height="60sp"/>
```

on the upper code side which gave me space :) to put my other things on the screen.

Comment: if u want fit each and every screen, you can use linear layouts with weight or use TableLayout

Comment: Can you please show me some example @SankarV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/jkmenu1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/atm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/currency"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/education"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coffee"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/birthday"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/beauty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/airport"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/classifieds"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks alot but now the images are http://i.imgur.com/f5PWOST.png how can I join them and fill the area

Comment: set the image as a background instead of source. When setting as a background use 9 patch images, because the images will get stretched.

Comment: Thanks it streched but how can i restrict the inside content not to override the footer space. It spread over the footer space too.

Comment: sorry, inside content not to override the footer space? am not clear with this statement. could you be more clear by showing the image?

Comment: Here is the screen . How can I leave small space right after the upper images and for footer space also http://i.imgur.com/iseqGGx.png
The images spread to all side . I want space for footer and little space below teh header too. how can I leave that

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/atm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/airport"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/birthday"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/currency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/birthday"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/classifieds"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/classifieds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beauty"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/education"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/birthday"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/birthday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/atm"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/coffee"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/airport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/beauty"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/beauty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/education"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/coffee"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coffee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/beauty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/atm"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have changed the source of the images I think you can modify it.

Comment: Thanks @Triode I change the images sources but with your layout every images scattered http://i.imgur.com/EnxJwzq.png

Comment: Instead of source can you set the Background for the image button as your images then it will work :)

Comment: Thanks it worked but how can I leave space for footer as well as above teh images?

Comment: You can set the marginTop for the first LinearLayout and also for the last layout.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

There are many examples on the web, check these out:

[Android TableLayout Example](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-tablelayout-example/)
[Android Sdk TableLayout](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/)
[GridLayout in Android](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/GridLayout-in-Android)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will go through the articles but do you have the quick idea to make it work for now

Comment: Instead of using a RelativeLayout, use 3 horizontal LinearLayouts, one for each row. Then, add android:layout_weight="1" to every ImageButton. The space will be fulfilled and all of them will have the same width, but they may not be completely square, they'll have a rectangular shape, all of them with the same dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. This will do exactly what you are looking for.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: @Homan It worked in some extent but the images are very far away how can I join then and fill the screen. all images are of same size http://i.imgur.com/f5PWOST.png

Comment: In ImageButton, change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent" and also add android:scaleType="fitXY" into it